# Can multiple models use the same turbo_stream_from tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, hotwire-rails

For applications with multiple `turbo_stream_from` tags like so:

```
<%= turbo_stream_from "posts" %>
<div id="posts">...</div>

<%= turbo_stream_from "comments" %>
<div id="comments">...</div>

... and in post model...

broadcast_update_to "posts", target: self

.. and in the comments model...

broadcast_update_to "comments", target: self
```

Is there any downside to unifying those two streams into one shared stream?

```
<%= turbo_stream_from "unified_stream" %>
<div id="posts">...</div>
<div id="comments">...</div>

... in the post model ....

broadcast_update_to "unified_stream", target: self

.. in the comments model ..

broadcast_update_to "unified_stream", target: self
```

Comment: It really depends on the contents of what is being updated I think, but in general I do not like comment model affecting the view that relies on post model. Seems like unnecessary coupling, and you would potentialy render more html than you actually need for a particular stream update.
In the future if the streams for those models diverge, you would have potentialy some annoying coupling to deal with too.
As a rule of thumb I would advice against it by default, but in really simple cases it is probably completly fine.

Comment: @kkp thanks for the thoughts. The example I gave is not from real code, I tried to distill it down to a simpler example. A better example might be a single turbo stream for the "admin" of a site, where multiple models are pushing updates, replaces, or appends. I hadn't seen anybody online writing about re-using a stream.

Comment: Okey I think I understand. So in general I would say that using one stream that gets signals to broadcrast from multiple different sources might be clunky. If the model changes one thing in the page that is wrapped in the stream, you will end up changing the whole page for 1 change (potentially, depending on how much the stream encapsulates).
In case of streams for admin and such, you might end up with problems of authorized users having access to some parts of the page that they should not have.

Comment: Also one stream depending on many different connections is more resource heavy than stream per client connection in ActionCable, it will get slower the more different connections to a stream there is (although it will take quite a bit of connections for this to be visible probably).
Sorry for two comments, run out of space.